# You tried vs You did try

Tags: grammar, tense

What is the difference between these sentences?

> You tried

and

> You did try

I have always used **tried** but then I heard **did try** in some film.
I have tried to find something about it, but I am still not sure.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check how to use quotation marks in English.  It is not the same as in many other languages  “ starts a quote and   ” ends it.

Comment: clue: use of emphatic auxiliaries.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when we mean to say something in the past, and use DID + verb in affirmative, it reinforces that the action, in fact, happened. For example:

> Anne: You didn't give me a present for my birthday...
>   John: No way! I **gave** you a present, it was a new dress!
>
> vs
>
> Anne: You didn't give me a present for my birthday...
>   John: No way! I **did give** you a present, it was a new dress!

In the first case, the phrase is plain objective. The second case, however, feels more appealing to the meaning that the situation (giving a present) really happened.

Comment: You should have made your answer more accurate by noting that the auxiliary "do" (and "does') and its past-tense variant are used to negate a statement. This use is NOT limited to the past tense.

Comment: And please mind your grammar. "I did give you a present, it was a new dress!" contains the blatant error known as the comma splice.

Comment: @Apollyon Take it easy. There is no comma splice if this is spoken English.